# swagger ui - issue in OPTIONS request to secure service

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I have deployed `Swagger UI (version swagger-ui-2.0.8) in tomcat`. This will define a set of APIs which invokes services deployed in Tibco BW in another domain. so far everything worked perfectly fine but when we just implemented our Tibco BW service as SSL `(uses **https**:xxxxxx:9090/user)`. Swagger send OPTIONS request since it is deployed in tomcat in another domain `(CORS request).` I have configured CORS for all responsee headers as "*".

The problem we have now is OPTIONS request from swagger does not have authentication header to hit BW service. How to achieve this. Please help

```
window.authorizations.add("Authorization", new ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", "Basic XXXXXXXX", "header"));
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think preflight OPTIONS request does have not to use authentication. Simply make the server respond to OPTIONS requests without any authentication.